# Read env variable from service worker file using workbox

Tags: javascript, webpack, service-worker, workbox, workbox-webpack-plugin

I'm working with `workbox-sw` and `workbox-webpack-plugin`
My src `sw.js` file at root folder (same level with my .env file)

How can I get env variables and accessing it into my src `sw.js` file

This is from my `webpack.config.js`

```
new workboxPlugin({
    globDirectory: 'dist',
    globPatterns: ['**/*.{html,js,css,svg,otf,png,jpg,gif}'],
    swSrc: './sw.js',
    swDest: path.join('public', 'sw.js')
})
```

Every help will be appreciated! Thanks everyone!

Comment: I proposed a solution over here (https://stackoverflow.com/a/57051150/1410035) that's for vue-cli, but it relies on a Webpack plugin which you can easily use without vue-cli. This might work for you too, just tweak the plugin to read the env vars you care about (it has access to everything).

Answer (score 0):

Because you're using `swSrc: './sw.js'`, that implies that the `./sw.js` file will be the basis for the final service worker file that's output. (It will have the precache information inserted into it as part of the build process.)

This means that you can process `./sw.js` however you'd like before the `workbox-webpack-plugin` runs, including modifying it by replacing placeholders with environment variables. I believe that `webpack.DefinePlugin` is normally used for that?

Comment: it didn't work, my workaround:

1. define a variable in webpack config in HtmlWebpackPlugin:
  `myVariable: process.env.MY_VAR`
2. insert into index.html:
  `<script>var MY_VAR = "<%= htmlWebpackPlugin.options.myVariable %>";`
3. get the variable in your service worker:
  `const myVariable = self.MY_VAR`;

Comment: I couldn't make this work either. Define plugins correctly replaces variables in main js bundle, but not in generated SW.

Comment: did you find any solution I am using nuxt js and I want to use the .env file in my custom service workers so if you have found any solution please reply