# Utilizing environment variables in firebase-messaging-sw.js in React Boilerplate

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase-cloud-messaging, service-worker, react-boilerplate

This is my firebase-messaging-sw.js file. What i require is to fetch environment variables from my .env file. Either directly or indirectly. I have tried other answers available here but to no avail. I am using React boilerplate and those answers just don't match up for me. Is there a way i could fetch these? Any help would be appreciated.

Code right now:

```
 importScripts(`https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.17.1/firebase-app.js`)
 importScripts(`https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.17.1/firebase-messaging.js`)
    
    firebase.initializeApp({
        apiKey: `AIz.....Cvg5E_Q`,
        authDomain: `example.firebaseapp.com`,
        databaseURL: `https://example.firebaseio.com`,
        projectId: `projectid`,
        storageBucket: `example.com`,
        messagingSenderId: `1...7`,
        appId: `1..............30`,
    })
```

Preferred way is to have it access from .env or some variable. By either importing or whatever. **P.s** Imports and require don't work in this service worker.

```
 importScripts(`https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.17.1/firebase-app.js`)
 importScripts(`https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.17.1/firebase-messaging.js`)
    
    firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig)
```

Answer (score 2):

In case if anyone is looking for an angular solution.

Create environment file for firebase in the environments folder

eg. `src/environments/fb-prod.ts`

And add your firebase content there

```
var configProd: any = {
    "apiKey": "PROD-KEY",
    "authDomain": "PROD-DOMAN",
    "projectId": "PROD-ProjId",
    "storageBucket": "PROD-s-bucket",
    "messagingSenderId": "PROD-msgSenderId",
    "appId": "PROD-appId",
    "measurementId": "PROD-measurementId"
}
```

Now create a script in your `package.json`. This script will create a file `fb-config.js` in assets/stubs/ folder.

```
"fb-config-prod": "tsc -out src/assets/stubs/fb-config.js src/environments/fb-prod.ts --module amd"
```

And, run this script before you run your build.

```
"build:prod": "npm run fb-config-prod; ng build --configuration=production",
```

In the `firebase-messaging-sw.js` file

change the following

```
// Give the service worker access to Firebase Messaging.
// Note that you can only use Firebase Messaging here. Other Firebase libraries
// are not available in the service worker.
importScripts('https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.10.0/firebase-app.js');
importScripts('https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.10.0/firebase-messaging.js');

// Initialize the Firebase app in the service worker by passing in
// your app's Firebase config object.
// https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup#config-object
firebase.initializeApp({
  apiKey: "-",
  authDomain: "-",
  projectId: "-",
  storageBucket: "-",
  messagingSenderId: "-",
  appId: "-",
  measurementId: "-"
});
```

to

```
// Give the service worker access to Firebase Messaging.
// Note that you can only use Firebase Messaging here. Other Firebase libraries
// are not available in the service worker.
importScripts('https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.10.0/firebase-app.js');
importScripts('https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.10.0/firebase-messaging.js');

importScripts('/assets/stubs/fb-config.js');

const config = configLocal || configDev || configProd;

// Initialize the Firebase app in the service worker by passing in
// your app's Firebase config object.
// https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup#config-object
firebase.initializeApp(config);
```

Comment: Thankyou so much. This worked for me. I am able to access the variables as well. Thankyou so much

Comment: But these value are still expose in assets / js file . Right ?

Answer (score 0):

I submitted an answer to solve this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62225339/how-to-use-process-env-in-a-react-service-worker/65011938#65011938). In summary you need to:

1. Create 2 `.env` files
2. Create a `firebase-messaging-sw.js` file in the **root folder** using your env vars
3. Install [cra-append-sw](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cra-append-sw)
4. Add `pre` scripts to your `package.json`

Check [my other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62225339/how-to-use-process-env-in-a-react-service-worker/65011938#65011938) for the implementation details.

Answer (score -2):

I think the easiest way to implement this but this will expose your API keys.

```
    importScripts('https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.2.0/firebase-app.js');
    importScripts('https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/8.2.0/firebase-messaging.js')
    const firebaseConfigDev = {
        apiKey: `AIz.....Cvg5E_Q`,
        authDomain: `example.firebaseapp.com`,
        databaseURL: `https://example.firebaseio.com`,
        projectId: `projectid`,
        storageBucket: `example.com`,
        messagingSenderId: `1...7`,
        appId: `1..............30`,
    };
    const firebaseConfigProd = {
        apiKey: `AIz.....Cvg5E_Q`,
        authDomain: `example.firebaseapp.com`,
        databaseURL: `https://example.firebaseio.com`,
        projectId: `projectid`,
        storageBucket: `example.com`,
        messagingSenderId: `1...7`,
        appId: `1..............30`,
    };
    
    const isProd = this.location.origin.includes("yourdomain.com");

// Initialize Firebase
firebase.initializeApp(isProd ? firebaseConfigProd : firebaseConfigDev);
const messaging = firebase.messaging();
```

Comment: Well that is what I didn't want to do but ended up doing so. This answers defeats the purpose of the question, which is, utilizing the ENV to get these API keys and other values. I would have to switch codes every time I have to make changes to these.

Comment: If you found the some much better way it would be great to share it here. I'm also having this problem on my side. Than kyou.

Comment: Unfortunately i have not, i did find a way to send it through URL params but it wasn't being done as it was supposed to be so i switched back to just hard coded stuff.